# Field returns a value when queried in CosmosDB data explorer but does not when queried via SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure-cosmosdb

I am running the following query in a serverless CosmosDB instance which returns the value below:

```
 SELECT
 c["TAF_Id"]
 , c["Request Form Name"]
 FROM c
 WHERE c["TAF_Id"] = '76215_1_9_001960'
```

[image]

However, when I try to run the query below via SSMS (account, database, object, credentials and field names are all correct), the Request Form Name field is not returning any value:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(​PROVIDER = 'CosmosDB',
                CONNECTION = 'Account=account;Database=database',
                OBJECT = 'object',
                SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'credential'
) WITH ( 
    [TAF_Id] VARCHAR(100)
    , [Request Form Name] VARCHAR(MAX)
) AS ROWS
WHERE [TAF_Id] = '76215_1_9_001960'
```

[image]

Does anyone have an idea where I went wrong here? This is a rather odd error.

Comment: What do you see if you just do a `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (...) AS X` without any `WITH`? Does it have the property but just renamed slightly due to the embedded spaces? TBH I would avoid spaces in property names anyway - I imagine they could be problematic in general

Comment: I don't know how big you're dataset but I would suggest the other obvious troubleshooting approach: remove the `WHERE` and see what you get. Maybe there are some unexpected spaces in the data values

Comment: I've been trying the query without the WITH clause but for some weird reason I keep getting booted out of the server connection. Error is: `A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)` This doesn't happen when I keep the WITH clause.

I don't have any say on how the fields are named, unfortunately.

Comment: Just tried it both on Synapse and SSMS and I'm getting the same error. `A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)`

Comment: You could try `EXEC sys.sp_Describe_first_result_set N'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(... ) x '` to see what properties it thinks is available and see if even getting the metadata succeeds

Comment: Try running query with key 
`SELECT [taf_id],[Request Form Name]
    FROM  OPENROWSET(
    'CosmosDB',
    'Account=<cosmos acc>;Database=<db name>;Key=<acc key>',
    tst
    ) AS  result
    WHERE [taf_id]='76215_1_9_001960'`.

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far. Unfortunately, it's still booting me out when I run the query without the WITH clause. I might have to check with our devs why this is happening (the field issue and the exception).

Comment: I retract my theory that the spaces are causing problems. When I tried to repro it didn't cause any issues https://i.stack.imgur.com/szqPc.png - the fact that you are getting SQL Serverless crashes might indicate that you have some corruption though. I'd open an Azure support request because you ought to be able to run that query without it crashing and the reason for the crash may be the same reason as the null column

Comment: Hey, thanks for looking into this even several hours after I made my original post. I'm thinking it might have something to do with network-related issues? I was using my mobile data earlier when I first encountered the issue. I tried running the query again using my home network and the query is running fine - which is odd because in our dataset, that field was the only one I was having issues with and everything else was outputting without issues. However, the exception error persisted even after changing networks.

Comment: Ah OK - I have previously seen an issue where some corruption was causing the entire SQL Serverless instance to crash (including killing the existing connection) and immediate reconnects would also fail as I presume it was failing over to another replica - in your case may well just be firewall though! Are you still getting the original issue where "Request Form Name" is NULL when you define it in the `WITH` clause? If so do you see that as a column from `SELECT *`?

Comment: @MiloUlver Can you provide input dataset and type of `Request Form Name`, because whenever the datatype mismatched and querying it as `varchar` you get null.